# Problems with CSS @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I'm developing an android app with phonegap and wanted to use custom fonts. To do so, I was trying to use CSS @font-face and I first made a little test to check if it worked the way I was expecting. I created a simple index.html file and a .css file in the same directory where I also copied the file with the font I wanted to use, which is in woff2 format. Here's the code for the css and html files:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto_Bold;
  src: url(/roboto_bold.woff2) format(woff2);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
p {
  font-family: Roboto_Bold;
}
```

```html
<p>prueba</p>
```

The problem is that, when I open index.html with Google Chrome, the font roboto_bold doesn't appear. The text is written with the browser default font, and no errors are shown in the console. I've tried everything to solve it (changing the font formats, checking the links, checking my browser version), but I couldn't find a solution. Any idea why @face-font isn't working?

Here is a screenshot of the files in my directory:
[image]

Comment: if there is in the same directory delete "/" before path to font, if not add "../" before

Comment: Have you checked your inspecter panel? (F12)... I bet it's a path issue relating to the font file

Comment: @Lee yeah, I checked the inspector, but the console doesn't show any error

Answer (score 2):

Remove the / infront of the font name, as your font file is in the same directory as your CSS file.

Also, try removing the underscore in the font name, and placing it in quotes - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'RobotoBold';
  src: url(roboto_bold.woff2) format(woff2);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    font-family: 'RobotoBold',sans-serif;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As your console is showing no errors, it's not a path related issue. I would suggest Chrome is unable to display WOFF2 files, and you may need to include extra versions of the file, such as WOFF. These are the two I use as a bare minimum.

You can create a whole font kit by uploading your font file (copyright applicable) to a webfont generator tool such as https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: So what does your inspector panel say? Does your console give any errors?

Comment: Try including a woff file version too. I use both woff and woff2 in my sites, and the fonts show up fine on all browsers.

Comment: I've just tried your suggetion, but still doesn't work

Comment: Does your network tab in Inspector show the font file being loaded?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check that... It doesn't show it. I guess that's the problem

Comment: Yeah, thinking, I don't think you'd get a 404 error for a font file not loading, only with img tags etc. Just try checking your path again. Is the font definitely called roboto_bold.woff2, and is DEFINITELY in the same folder as your CSS file?

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of your files in the directory?

Comment: I've uploaded it in the question

Comment: Are you correctly callign your CSS file in your HTML file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121925/discussion-between-lee-and-ziessel).

Comment: `code` <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" /> `code`

Comment: OKay, running out of options now. HAve you tried removing the underscore and using single quotes?

Comment: sure, I've tried. I'm gonna try the same code in another computer, to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in a different computer with a version of Chrome for another OS and it worked fine. It seems it was all a problem of platform